Pitch accent of の particle with nouns
What's the pitch accent of の, when it comes after 頭高, 中高, 尾高 and 平板 nouns?
Based on my experience, it attaches low after 頭高, 中高 and 尾高 nouns, and attaches high after 平板 nouns, is it correct assumption?

To my understanding, it's the same as for other particles, and that's a property of the noun (i.e. its accent pattern), rather than the particle.

See also the Japanese pitch accent article at Wikipedia, particularly the #Trailing particles and auxiliaries section.

の may remove accents from 尾高 nouns to become 平板 in certain situations.
E.g: 休み↓　→　休みの日
男↓　→　男の人↓ (the 男の part is 平板)
This is not guaranteed to happen in every case.
の may remove accents from 中高 nouns to also become 平板 in certain situations. The accent must be -2 and the last mora must be ー (long vowel)、ン、or イ.
E.g: ニホ↓ン (日本) → ニホンの (日本の)
This is not guaranteed to happen in every case.
の deleting accents in 尾高 nouns and in the special cases of 中高 nouns (refer previous paragraph) does not occur in numbers, quantities, amounts, volumes, stage names, and older place names.
There is also some cases where the devoicing within the noun results in the の accent deletion not taking place like in 試験 (シケ↓ン) due to the devoicing between the シ and the ケ. This devoicing point gets more complicated but just keep this in mind that devoicing can change some stuff which results in either the の deleting or not deleting.
EDIT: The Wikipedia article linked by Eirikr should have more info and I think it mentions some of the devoicing stuff.
